# Current Server Status

Tags: php

I know that I have seen a method out there in PHP that when called will give me the current CPU status, but I cannot remember it, and google searches are not coming up with anything for me.

Basically, I have a chat program, and I need to make sure that it doesn't wreak havoc on the server.  So I would like to, when a message is posted (as that is the only time that PHP is used, otherwise just straight .txt file), check to see what the status of the server is.  That way I can regulate how often ajax requests are sent out by the client, depending on the health of the server.

Comment: good thinking - as a side note, i would probably cache the 'status' page for a few seconds, that way your clients won't hammer the function getting the cpu load either :)

Comment: Yeah, it is cached.  It actually gets sent back as a part of the JSON response with the new posts (in the .txt file)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are on a Linux-based server, you can use [`sys_getloadavg`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sys-getloadavg.php), which will get you the system load average :

> Returns three samples representing the
>   average system load (the number of
>   processes in the system run queue)
>   over the last 1, 5 and 15 minutes,
>   respectively.

This should be better than using a "snapshot" of the CPU-load at a given instant : the 1 minute and 5 minutes values are quite interesting, as they give you an average value for a short period of time.

It also gives takes into account more that only the CPU load -- for more informations, you can take a look at the [Load average page on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_average).

But note that this function is not implemented on windows platform.

Which mean you'll have to make that call conditionnal, depending on the underlying operatinf system.

Comment: Thanks!  That is exactly what I was searching for.  I am on a Linux box, so that works perfectly.